# data loading was blocked Select 2 yii2

Tags: php, yii2, jquery-select2

I worked with select2 widget and it works with a single, but when I put two select2 widget the second widget is blocked. I need your help please.
this is my select2 code:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'idClient')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Client::find()->all(),'idClient','nom'),
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Selectionée le Client ...'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true
    ],
]); ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'idDevis')->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Devis::find()->all(),'idDevis','reference'),
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Selectionée le Devis ...'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true
    ],
]); ?>
```

the result is like that :

[image]

Comment: sure if Devis::find()->all() returns data ?

Comment: set when I inspect html code I can see all  devis's data

Comment: If it's infinite loading, then it's probably a problem with JavaScript code (syntax error?).

Comment: yes I think that because in console i get this error in jquery.js file  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property 'guid' on string '#commande-idClient'` but how I can fix that. I was update all og this file but I get the same error